# SQL Remove Duplicate header when doing inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to Remove the Duplicate Header of my Query...

`here's my query`

```
Select  po.BranchOrderNumber,pod.ItemCode, pod.ItemDescription From  RetailPosOrders po 
INNER JOIN RetailPosOrderDetails pod
ON po.BranchOrderID = pod.OrderID
```

my query's result now look's like this.

[image]

now what I want is something like this.

[image]

thanks in advance. I was planning to use this on `Report builder`.. I am using Microsoft Sql Server 2014.

Comment: I think you have to do it in the application level if you are going to display it using application

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea trying to do it in the query. It should be managed at report level.

Comment: @Backtrack yes I would never do this if it's only in an application lvl... but I am using `microsoft report builder` which is I don't know how to manipulate the dataset there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the type of transformation that is best done at the application level.  It is possible in SQL, but do recall that SQL queries and result sets -- by default -- are unordered.  Your desired results have an ordering.

But, you can do this using `row_number()`:

```
Select (case when row_number() over (partition by po.BranchOrderNumber order by pod.ItemCode) = 1
             then po.BranchOrderNumber else ''
        end) as BranchOrderNumber
       pod.ItemCode, pod.ItemDescription
From RetailPosOrders po INNER JOIN
     RetailPosOrderDetails pod
     ON po.BranchOrderID = pod.OrderID
Order by po.BranchOrderNumber, pod.ItemCode;
```

This assumes that `po.BranchOrderNumber` -- despite its name -- is stored as a string (the leading zeroes suggest that this is the case).

Also, a couple of important things:

- The outer `order by` needs to be the same as the fields used in the `over` clause.
- The fields need to uniquely define each row in the result set.  The `order by` in SQL is not stable, meaning that keys with the same value can appear in any order, even for different runs of the same query.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to do this in Mssql server itself**.

I think you have to do it in the application level if you are going to display it using console/ win / web application.

Comment: Sure there is a way to do this on server - most requirements are possible to implement on sql, just sometimes this is not a good solution.